# Log user out when s/he visits certain page

Tags: kentico

I have different Kentico microsites (site 1, site 2) that are password protected. Each site has a separate pair of userid/pw to log in (site 1 > userid1/pw1; site 2 > userid2/pw2). The problem I have is there are a couple of users that have access to both sites, so if they log into site 1, they can't right away log into site 2 without having to clear cache first.

I understand it's not a good practice to do the above, but to temporarily fix the issue at hand, is it possible to automatically end users' current session (log them out so to speak) when they visit certain page. That way those users can log in site 1 and 2 more easily.

I only have access to admin but don't have access to backend, file system stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a custom web part which does checking to see if the current user has access to given microsite.  If not, log them out.  This web part would be placed on the master page template of each microsite.

Another option is to assign roles to the user(s).  This would allow one user account for 1 person across multiple microsites.